# Shouldn't non correlated queries be executed only once in a not in statement?

Tags: query-performance, oracle19c

Recently I came across a strange behavior that I can't explain and needed some help to understand why it happens that way.

Imagine the following scenario: I want to retrieve all classes that happens in all rooms that the user has no access to. To get this I am using the `not in` in a query like the following:

```
select id 
  from class
 where room_id not in 
     (
         select room_id 
           from user_room
          where user_id = 123
     )
```

I though that because the inner query (inside the `not in`) is independent from the outer query (non correlated queries), the inner query would be executed only once, but what is happening is that it's being executed once for every record in the class table. This causes a big performance hit.

The reason why I state that it's been executed once for every class record is because of the Explain Plan for the query, which is the following:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                |     1 |    59 |   144   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS ANTI |                |     1 |    59 |   144   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| CLASS          |   137 |  6302 |   144   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN| USER_ROOM_UK   |     4 |    52 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am assuming that the step with the ID 1 is the `not in` query been executed for every record of the table class. Is my interpretation correct?

If I replace the `not in` query by the values returned by the query, something like:

```
select id 
  from class
 where room_id not in 
     (
         1, 2, 3
     )
```

The Explain Plan now shows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |       |   125 |  5750 |   144   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| CLASS |   125 |  5750 |   144   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So this is why I am assuming that the inner query is being executed once for each record of outer query.

I would like to understand why this is happening. Shouldn't it be only executed once because I am dealing with non correlated queries? Or is any of my assumptions wrong?

Also, is there a way to tell Oracle Engine to execute the inner query only once?

Any feedback is appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: You've tagged 2 completely different RDBMS here. Which are you *actually* using?

Comment: @Larnu sorry, by bad. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my interpretation correct?

You can check this by executing the query using **gather_plan_statistics** hint like below

```
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ /* my_mark01 */id 
  from class c
 where c.room_id not in
 (
     select room_id
       from user_room ur
      where user_id = 123
 );

select t.*
  from v$sql s, table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(s.sql_id, null, 'allstats last')) t
 where s.sql_text like '%my_mark01%'
   and not s.sql_text like '%v$sql%';
```

This will show you **Starts** metric for each plan row to understand how many times it was actually executed and **A-rows** metric will show the quantity of rows actually fetched.

Usualy Oracle is smart enough to avoid doing extra job in such cases. E.g. on a bit modified query from description(used it because the problem query gives completely different and correct plan on my test environment)

```
create table class (id number(10), room_id number(10), description varchar2(50));
create table user_room (user_id number(10), room_id number(10), description varchar2(50));
create unique index user_room_uk on user_room(user_id, room_id) tablespace drnindexes;

insert into class
select level, trunc((level-1)/100)+1, level||' '||(trunc((level-1)/100)+1) from dual connect by level <= 500;
commit;

insert into user_room
select (case when level <= 3 then 123 else 345 end), level, null from dual connect by level <= 5;
commit;    

select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ /* my_mark02 */id 
  from class c
 where not exists
 (
     select 1
       from user_room ur
      where ur.user_id = 123
        and ur.room_id = c.room_id
 );
     
 select t.*
 from v$sql s, table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(s.sql_id, null, 'allstats last')) t
 where s.sql_text like '%my_mark02%'
   and not s.sql_text like '%v$sql%';
```

shows

```
SQL_ID  fu0qyzn2anmgm, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ /* my_mark02 */id 
   from class 
c
  where not exists
  (
      select 1
        from user_room ur
      
 where ur.user_id = 123
         and ur.room_id = c.room_id
  )
 
Plan hash value: 300864768
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name         | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |              |      1 |        |    200 |00:00:00.01 |      29 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS ANTI |              |      1 |    500 |    200 |00:00:00.01 |      29 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| CLASS        |      1 |    500 |    500 |00:00:00.01 |      26 |
|*  3 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN| USER_ROOM_UK |      5 |      1 |      3 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   3 - access("UR"."USER_ID"=123 AND "UR"."ROOM_ID"="C"."ROOM_ID")
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

that whereas the quantity of rows retrieved from Class table was 500 - the Starts count for user_room table scans is only 5 - the quantity of distinct room_id values in class table.

> why this is happening

Usually such things happen because of incorrect statistics on tables/indexes or some specific optimizer setting parameters configured on particular instance.
Did you try to gather statistics for described tables to actualize it?

> Also, is there a way to tell Oracle Engine to execute the inner query
> only once?

If I correctly understand - subquery will give you relatively small amount of rows. In this case you can try to force Oracle to use hash anti join by using [hash_aj hint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Unnesting-of-Nested-Subqueries.html#GUID-DA7A69AA-156D-4F1B-9E29-DAE9D230D9B5)
like (unfortunately, can;t test properly on my env because the problem doesn't reproduce and oracle select hash join anti na automatically)

```
select  id 
  from class c
 where c.room_id not in
 (
     select /*+ hash_aj swap_join_inputs(ur) */ room_id
       from user_room ur
      where user_id = 123
 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! I read the link you sent regarding query unnesting and I realized that even though the inner query is non correlated, it will not be unnested by the oracle engine because is being used in a NOT IN. Non correlated queries are only unnested if used in an EXISTS or IN. Using the hint you provided solved my problem. Another thing I will do that I realized with your answer is that this can also be achieved with NOT EXISTS, I will compare the performance of both and will use the fastest. Thank you very much for your help!!!